# Why does this stream function result in an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have written a function to be piped into that will log the supplied arguments to the console.

```
function sconsole() {
    var stream = new Stream.Transform({objectMode: true}),
        foo = [].slice.call(arguments);

    stream._transform = function (data, encoding, callback) {
        console.log.apply(null, foo);
        callback(null, data);
    };

    return stream;
}
```

Example use:

```
stream
  .pipe(sconsole('foo'))
  .pipe(...);
```

But when used in the final position of a sequence of pipe invocations, it causes the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
```

Why?

Comment: I would check out the values coming out of sconsole. Not sure about new Stream either unless you have a function or object called Stream somewhere around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix/pipe `objectMode` and non-`objectMode` streams together like that because they work with different data types.

However, if you have node v0.12+ or io.js, you *could* use something like `readableObjectMode: true`, which sets the readable side of your transform stream for reading objects, but writing bytes as normal. You can do something similar for the other way around with `writableObjectMode: true` (`objectMode: true` is equivalent to setting both of these properties to `true`). This way you can convert between one stream type to another.

Comment: Thanks very much. So you're saying the position in the pipe chain affects the data type inbound into the function?

Comment: Not really, it's how your stream is instantiated/configured that determines what kind of input you expect to receive and what kind of output there will be. Before node v0.12 and io.js, it was either only binary data/strings or only objects in both directions. The newer versions allow for independently changing input and output types. It is important to make sure you are piping streams so that the output type of one stream matches the input type of the next stream though.

Comment: OK. So if I have something like the following, how should I configure the `console` function so that it fits? 

```stream.pipe(tap(file => temp.css = file.contents.toString()))
             .pipe(sconsole('foo'));
```

Comment: It depends, what type of stream does `tap()` return? Does it push non-Buffer/string types (e.g. `{}` or `[]` or `1234`) to its readable side or not?

Comment: How can I find out? Suspect it is returning bytes.

Comment: You could either attach a `data` handler to the stream and check the type of the argument (e.g. `Buffer.isBuffer(chunk) || typeof chunk === 'string') passed to the handler, or you could look at the internal private properties of the stream: `tapStream._readableState` (there should be properties that store the objectMode settings).